# Android: add an array of Switches in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, switch-statement

I want to add some switches in a linear layout (declared as a view, not as a LinearLayout). I tried this, but it gets me an error:

```
numberDevices = 3; //This is going to be used after
Switch[] switches = new Switch[numberDevices];
for (int i = 0; i < numberDevices; i++) {
    switches[i].setTextOn("ON");
    switches[i].setTextOff("OFF");
    switches[i].setId(i);

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(switches[i]);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: probably because you are trying to cast a view with linear layout which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created any Switches, you've just made an empty array. You need to create the switches first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberDevices; i++) {
    switches[i] = new Switch(linearLayout.getContext());
    ...
}
```

Comment: I noticed this 5 minutes after making the question, hahaha! But, thanks for answering. This is the correct answer